# Time stamp date to mm/dd/yyyy in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field st_ts that shows as 07/09/2021 5:20:52 PM. How do I get it to show as just 07/09/2021? I've tried `TO_DATE('ST_TS','MM/DD/YYYY')` but it isn't working. In there where clause I have to do `TRUNC(ST_TS) = '09-JUL-2021'` to select the date. Thanks.

Comment: `alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy'`. To filter by date you need [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1): `date '2021-07-13'` which is of type `date`

Comment: This: `TRUNC(ST_TS) = '09-JUL-2021'` is something you should never do. Never compare a date with a string. Use a date literal instead: `TRUNC(ST_TS) = DATE '2021-07-09'`.

Comment: `mm/dd/yyyy` is my favourite format because you never know what the date is it unless you scroll through all the rows to find something outstanding. At least ANSI `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: What is the tool you are using to display the date? It has probably a a setting how to display dates. You can even google it , e.g. SQL-Developer date setting.

Comment: This: `TO_DATE('ST_TS','MM/DD/YYYY')` must lead to an exception, because with single quotes you make `'ST_TS'` a string literal. You then try to make it a date (by applying `TO_DATE` on it), but the string doesn't even look remotely like a date. You probably want `TO_CHAR(ST_TS, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` instead, i.e. appy `TO_CHAR` (not `TO_DATE`) on the column `ST_TS` to get from the datetime to the date string. And please don't ever say "but it isn't working" without telling us what happens. If you are getting an error tell us that and tell us which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what that column's datatype is. I *presume* it is `DATE`. If that's so, have a look at the following examples:

```
SQL> create table test (st_Ts date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (to_date('07/09/2021 05:20:52', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

1 row created.
```

Altering the session and setting date format mask:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

ST_TS
----------
07/09/2021

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

ST_TS
-------------------
09.07.2021 05:20:52
```

Applying `TO_CHAR` function with desired format mask:

```
SQL> select to_char(st_ts, 'mm/dd/yyyy') result from test;

RESULT
----------
07/09/2021
```

Truncating `DATE` value "resets" time portion to midnight:

```
SQL> select trunc(st_ts) result2 from test;

RESULT2
-------------------
09.07.2021 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Therefore, you have various options. It depends on what you're up to. If you're using some reporting tool, I'd suggest you to set field's format mask there. If you just want to display it differently, use `TO_CHAR`. For the whole session length, alter the session.